# How to add more ROMs to MAME on X-Arcade

Tags: emulation, mame, x-arcade

We take the off-hours entertainment seriously here at Stack Exchange, so we got one of the [X-Arcade cabinets](http://www.xgaming.com/store/arcade-machines/product/x-arcade-machine-cabinet/) installed at the office.

Trouble is - we can't seem to be able to add more ROMs to it.

The whole thing's backed by a PC running Windows 8. We know where the ROMs are supposed to be located. If we drop additional zipped ROMs into `C:\MAX2.10\MAME\roms` and then run mame64.exe, they are recognized just fine. However, the frontend runner that the cabinet comes with doesn't seem to be able to pick up the new games we dropped in.

Hitting <kbd>F5</kbd> doesn't seem to make it refresh. It looks like the frontend software is capturing all keyboard input and interpreting it in its own way.

How can we make this work so that we don't have to keep bringing up the task manager, killing the frontend, and running MAME directly? In a pinch, it'll probably do, but there doesn't seem to be a way to get a full list of available games from MAME itself, so having them show up in the cabinet's frontend emulator would be best.

Comment: Are you using Maximus Arcade as the front-end? If so, after adding new roms to the MAME ROMs folder like you said, you should just need to open Maximus Arcade, right-click anywhere on the screen and choose "Refresh Game List".

Comment: @Alex That doesn't seem to work. The front-end seems to intercept all input and does precisely nothing with anything that's not scrolling through the games list or selecting a game. Is there a config utility or something that I'm missing?

Comment: I believe the shortcut to get to preferences is `Right Ctrl` + `p`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

New game ROMs can be put in the "PUT MAME ROMS HERE!" folder found on your desktop (do not extract the .zip files).

If you add new ROM files to the roms folder, you will need to tell Maximus Arcade to Refresh the Game List. To do this,

- Open Preferences (Use the keyboard's RIGHT-SIDE CONTROL KEY (NOT LEFT) CONTROL+P while in the front end, or the Preferences link found at `C:\MAX 2.10\Frontend`).
- Choose the Configuration tab.
- Next to "Configuration for" choose the emulator you want to look for new roms in (example MAME) from the drop-down list.
- Next click on the "Scan" tab at the bottom, and put a check next to "Force rescan of media folder".
- Close preferences. Your screen may be blank for a few minutes while it is updating.

If your ROMs don't appear or don't work see our ROMS help page.

Comment: Note that *mame* adds some files into your 'mame' dir ( `~/.mame` ) every time you load a game, afaik a `nvram` file in `~/.mame/nvram/`, so if you copy a `.mame` tree from another computer, there may be some inconsistencies between your 'rom' dir (usually `~/.mame/roms/`) and the `nvram` files, thus having errors like "*Fatal error: Required files are missing*", while the zip are there... Clean the `nvram` files [beware you lose games data, like high score etc...] and try again.

Answer (score -3):

Here's what to do. On MAME go to `File`, then click `Audit all games`. It should take a while, but it searches if any games work. Then try the game. It should work. If not, go to `Options`, then `Directories` and click `Show directions`. For then locate the `roms` folder, where your game is, then click `OK` ON THE ROMS FOLDER ONLY! Then it should work.