# Zsnes not automatically load through maximus arcade

Tags: emulation, zsnes

In maximus configuration, I place this

---

Executable: `F:\Games\zsnesw151\zsnesw.exe`

Media (roms): `F:\Games\zsnesw151\roms\`

---

When I try to play any of the games (roms) through maximus arcade it only start the zsnes application but does not automatically load the selected rom.

Comment: It's been a long time since I've been heavily activs but when did we start allowing emulation questions?

Comment: @Steven I'm sorry, i din't know the rules, i saw some of zsnes emulator question here, so i thought its ok to ask about emulators. And about my problem, i try it on my window 7 pc and no problem at all, is it maybe my problem is because im using windows 10 and it not allow to make it happen

Comment: @RLH Emulation questions have been allowed for a while. For example, see *[How to add more ROMs to MAME on X-Arcade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/114966/181240)* by Arqade moderator Adam Lear from 2013. Questions about finding ROMS or other illegal content would be off topic however.